# Fear and disgust in openvino Model Emotions-recognition-retail

Tags: intel, pre-trained-model, openvino

In model Emotions-recognition-retail-003 not include fear and disgust classes.
Will there be 2 classes in the new release?
Is there a openvino model now that has these classes

Comment: Lol, from the title I assumed it was a joke/reference on the "fear and loathing in ..." meme with a slight distortion, from Hunter S. Thompson's book and the movie of the same name.  https://film.avclub.com/fear-and-loathing-in-las-vegas-captured-the-fading-myth-1826274302.  But no, those words are literal things and you're simply asking about both of them.

Comment: LOVE the title.

Comment: Since this is a roadmap question, perhaps you should ask it on the openvino forum: https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-distribution-of-openvino-toolkit

Answer (score 0):

These classes were intentionally left out due to ambiguity with other emotions and under-representation in training data. There's no current plans to bring these classes to the mix.